# Why does it seem to decrease probability to roll more times?

Tags: probability, dice

I am looking how to find the probability of rolling 10 sixes in 60 rolls. After reading [Calculate probabilities. 40 sixes out of a 100 fair die rolls & 20 sixes out of a 100 fair die roll](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586953/calculate-probabilities-40-sixes-out-of-a-100-fair-die-rolls-20-sixes-out-of), it seems that I can use the following formula: $60 \choose 10$$(\frac{1}{6})^{10}$$(1-\frac{1}{6})^{60-10}$

That comes to about 13.7%. So far, so good.

But then I decided to test it. What about getting 10 sixes in 120 rolls?
$120 \choose 10$$(\frac{1}{6})^{10}$$(\frac{5}{6})^{120-10}$

That's only 0.37%! I'm getting something wrong, but what?

Comment: Do you mean 10 exactly or "at least 10"?

Comment: I meant exactly - that's what I must be missing, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula you quote is for getting exactly (not at least) $10\ 6$'s in $60$ rolls.  The factor $(1-\frac 16)^{60-10}$ ensures that the other dice roll something other than $6$.  Your extension is correct for getting exactly (not at least) $10\ 6$'s in $120$ rolls.  The expected number is $20$, so it is not surprising that the probability has decreased-you are farther from the expected number.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185241/probability-of-rolling-sixes-in-50-rolls-of-a-fair-die I've read this one too; the OP seems to have my exact difficulty. Is there no quicker formula for this than $60 \choose 1$$(\frac{1}{6})^{1}$$(\frac{5}{6})^{60-1}$$ + $$60 \choose 2$$(\frac{1}{6})^{2}$$(\frac{5}{6})^{60-2}$$ + $$60 \choose 3$$(\frac{1}{6})^{3}$$(\frac{5}{6})^{60-3}... $ up to 9, and then subtract the answer from 1 to get the probability for 10 or more sixes in 60 rolls?

Comment: I think this question is just the reverse.  OP was surprised that the chance of exactly $10$ sixes went down.  Your formula is for (assuming you stop at $9$) less than $10\ 6$'s  I don't know an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

What you've calculated (correctly) are the probabilities that you get *exactly* $10$ sixes in $60$ rolls and $120$ rolls, respectively. If you think about this, it makes sense that the probability of the latter should be lower. Intuitively, there are more possibilities for how many sixes show up in the second case.